# Installing CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

I am wanting to install CodeIgnitor on my hosting account, but I'm a little confused.

The documentation says:

> "CodeIgniter is installed in four
>   steps:
>
> 1.Unzip the package.
>
> 2.Upload the CodeIgniter folders and files to your server. Normally the
>   index.php file will be at your root.
>
> 3.Open the application/config/config.php file
>   with a text editor and set your base
>   URL.   If you intend to use encryption
>   or sessions, set your encryption key."

I'm having trouble getting my head around No. 2; It says to chuck everything into the root dir of my server, which is fine, I can do that, BUT, the codeigniter files that I upload also has an index.php page.

And my website files are also located in the root folder. If I upload all the codeigniter files to my root dir, and replace the default index.php file that codeigniter tells me to upload with my own websites index.php file? Is that what you're supposed to do?

Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the complete steps for installing the codeigniter http://www.webexperttips.com/tag/codeigniter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your current website, you may not want to replace the index.php until your new website is ready to go live.  If you are trying to tie the two together, I recommend fully porting your current website in to CodeIgniter if at all possible.

Otherwise, I recommend installing CodeIgniter in a folder under the root directory and modifying its config file to point to it.

Comment: My existing index.php file doesn't have any php in it, its just named with a php extension for consistency reasons, and the index.php that comes with C.I seems to be just a welcome page, so it is safe to replace that with my existing one? :)

Comment: But are you using your current index.php?  If not, go for it. Replace it and build your site.

Comment: Yeah, I would like to replace CodeIgnitor's index.php with my own current one :) - Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: I think I may not have been clear enough.  The contents of CodeIgniter's index.php is an essential part of the framework.  Without it, the framework overall won't work.  What I was saying was that you could replace **your** index.php with **CodeIgniter's** index.php.

Comment: @Lucifer, make sure you DO NOT DELETE the Codeigniter `index.php` file. That makes your codeigniter setup work.  If you are confused simply read up on the CodeIgniter topic, and view the *how to videos* on their website (they reference a blog, but it applies to a standard website too).

Comment: @Jakub: Aaahhhhhhh! I deleted the index.php file and it broke lol (before I saw your comment) - thanks for the advice, I am checkin' it out now :)

Comment: @simshaun - Oohhhhhhh, I get it :), sleep deprivation is not fun! I am checking out the video tutorials on their site :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

another way of doing this is to first through your control panel is to create a subdomain like myci.yoursite.com, and select the folder for it as /var/www/myci (which would usually be automatic)

upload unzipped codeigniter files in /var/www/myci.  if any default index.php is created there it is usually safe to overwrite it.  if any default index.html etc is created you may have to delete them.  any cgi-bin etc can be safely left untouched.

you should be able to see your site as http://myci.yoursite.com/

one of the first things you should do is edit your system/application/config/config.php and correct the $config['base_url']

Comment: Can I ask you, if I create subdomain, I can then have my real index.php page (the one with my websites content) in the root dir? please? :)

Comment: www.yoursite.com in /var/www/main can have your real index.php and www2.yoursite.com in /var/www/sub1 can be the codeigniter index.php

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the CI index page is a config page, not a welcome page.  Your "real" index page is NOT the index page that you are thinking it is.

Your site address should be like this

www.sitename.com/index.php/main

main is simply the controller name that calls the opening page.(I use main, you can use any name you want)

if Main is your controller that points to the opening page,m you would name youre first function in the main controller "index"

```
Class Main extends controller{
function index(){
$this->load->view('main page name'); 
}
}
```

All pages views in CI are called by a controller, there are no free floating pages

Comment: Ahh, I'm beginning to understand now. Is it possible to "merge (right word?)" my existing website template i bought into codeignitor so its all like views and controllers and models etc? Or to create new views, would i need to rewrite the whole website template from scratch?

Comment: Yes Im sure you could use the template, remember Codeigniter is not design, a template is.  Use the controller and model to select and manipulate your data and send it to the views(your template)

Answer (score 0):

First of all back up all your existing files in your root folder, Install Codeigniter following the guide which is located at 
`https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/installation/`.

Your index.php file is different when compared with Codeigniter index.php file, Codeigniter uses index.php file as a config file to set the required paths and to load different classes including Router, this way the default Welcome page is loaded indicating proper installation of Codeigniter.

You can later place the `application` and `system` folder out of your public directory, while changing the settings in Codeigniter's index.php  file